# Python3 hashing function override

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Does anyone know what kind of hash function python3 uses? Is there any way to reimplement the function accept lists as keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`hash()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash); object types implement a [`__hash__` hook function](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

No, you cannot make it accept `list`s, but subclasses of `list` could be made to work. Do take into account that not keeping the hash *and* equality tests stable for keys **will** break your dictionary.

You'd be better off storing *`tuple`s* as keys, however. Turning a list into a tuple is trivial enough:

```
my_dictionary[tuple(my_list)] = my_value
```

Comment: Also using a `frozenset` as a hashable equivalent of list might be a good idea if order of items is not important.

Comment: Thanks for the tip "not keeping the hash and equality tests stable for keys will break your dictionary" saved me a lot of debugging.. :-)